# In which segment global const variable will stored and why

Tags: c, constants

after applying `const` qualifier to any global variable  increases the size of text segment.
so, why global const variable will stored in text segment.

I have tried these codes

```
const int i = 5;
int main()
{
        return 0;
}
```

output of command: size a.out

> text     data     bss     dec     hex filename
>   1080        496      16     1592        638 a.out

```
int i = 5;
int main()
{
        return 0;
}
```

output of command: size a.out

> text     data     bss     dec     hex filename
>   1076        500      16     1592        638 a.out

---

Comment: It is stored in the text segment because the text segment is read-only (not writable) so placing the variable there enforces constness.  It shouldn't be an issue for you, regardless of where it is placed.

Comment: But const qualifier means to be change by some other means...then what is the point to store it in text

Comment: Que? Are you thinking of `volatile`?  `const` means 'cannot be changed'.

Comment: yes, keyword `const` doesn't turn a variable into a constant! A symbol with the `const` qualifier merely means that the symbol cannot be used for assignment. This makes the value re ad -onl y through that symbol; .So it will put in text segment (read-only).

Comment: we may change value of const variable by using pointer....so if it will stored in text segment then how it will change ??

Answer (score 1):

As the text segment is read-only it can be shared among all the processes that are running your program, thus potentially reducing memory consumption. This is even more important for shared libraries, which may be used by many programs. Whether this is what actually happens depends on your operating system's behaviour.

Putting const variables with static storage in the text segment ensures that this mechanism is exploited as much as possible.

Comment: But const qualifier means to be change by some other means...then what is the point to store it in text...we cant change its value

Comment: No, no, no, no. `const` means *this will not change*. There are ways to circumvent this because they may be needed in certain situations, but they are not guaranteed to work.

Comment: The fact that you can jump down a bridge doesn't mean that you should, nor that it would be anybody's fault but yours if you hurt yourself by doing it.

Comment: By declaring a variable `const` you tell the compiler that you do not intend changing it. If you lie to the compiler, be prepared to face the consequences.

Comment: I m not getting you........in embedded systems const variables are used like this only...so that value of these variables can be change by hardware port, other threads or by other way.

Comment: You are confusing `const` with `volatile`. In embedded systems const data may well be put in ROM.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler has better opportunity for optimization with `const` variables. Here, it looks like the `const` value is incorporated into the code and hence the increase in the size of the text segment.